# Can instantiate object of class in which a bean is autowired

Tags: java, spring

There are two classes class A and class B. class B is spring bean and autowired in class A. Class A is not spring bean.

```
public class A {

       int a,c;

        public A(int a, int c ){
         this.a = a;
         this.c = c;
        }

        @Autowired 
        B b 

        // some logic 

     }

class C {
         // Can object will be created 
         A obj = new A(10,12);
}
```

if code will compile what will happen I mean object of B will be created.

Comment: How are you having two variables in A, having name b?

Comment: @SumitDesai I have renamed the variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object of class B will be created at application start-up, but will not be injected into instance of A, since it's not a spring  managed bean.